# Why is my Angular Service not assigning a filtered result to my property?

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I setup a service called 'bankService' which is being used by my 'user' component. The 'user' component is receiving the data from the service correctly but I am unable to assign a filtered result to my 'currentAccount' property. I am filtering by 'id' from the list of 'accounts' that is being returned from my service. Any help with an explanation would be appreciated!

**Model**

```
export interface Account {
  id: number;
  accountHolder: string;
  checking: number;
  savings: number;
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { elementAt, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Account } from '../models/Account';
import { Transaction } from '../models/Transaction';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BankServiceService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/accounts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAccounts(): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.http.get<Account[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Account } from 'src/app/models/Account';
import { BankServiceService } from 'src/app/services/bank-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css'],
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  currentAccount: Account[] = [];
  accountId: number;
  accountHolder: string;
  checkingAmount: number;
  savingsAmount: number;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private bankService: BankServiceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // gets the parameter for the url (the param is the account id)
    this.accountId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log('id: ', this.accountId);

    // pulls in all accounts
    this.bankService
      .getAccounts()
      .subscribe(
        (accounts) =>
          (this.currentAccount = accounts.filter(
            (account) => account.id === this.accountId
          ))
      );

    console.log('current account: ', this.currentAccount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, your issue is this one:

- the account id received from the backend is a number
- the account id pulled from the url is a string

**In the filter function you are using strict equality, and that's why no account id passes the condition in the filter callback**

You can switch from strict equality to loose equality (`==`) or do something like this for the filter callback:

```
(account) => account.id.toString() === this.accountId
```